# Handle cookies with Doc viewer in website

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, cookies, google-document-viewer

I am writing a website which will display documents using Google doc viewer. I am setting cookies when user logged in to website and validating them for every request. As i am using DocViewer plugin in client side to display, it is not sending cookies and failing authentication to access resource. How can i overcome this?

My doc viewer code is like this :

```
var url = configService.getDocumentDownloadPath()+'?documentId='+$scope.document.documentId;
url = 'http://docs.google.com/viewer?url='+ encodeURIComponent(url) + '&embedded=true';
```

Any suggestions?